# many to many table JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, relational-database

I am trying to set up a many to many relationship between patient and nurses.

I need the PatientID to be assigned to a NurseID; so there is a relationship between the patient and nurse. Is this possible via a function TABLE JOIN?

So far I have three tables:

```
Patient 
(
PatientID (PK), 
Forename, 
surname, 
gender, 
date of birth, 
address, 
illness, 
prioirty
)

seen_by 
(
ID(PK),
PatientID(FK), 
NurseID(FK)
) 

Nurse 
(
NurseID(PK),  
Forename, 
surname
)
```

I have added a foreign contraint to the seen_by table to add a relationship between patients and nurse.

```
Patient (PatientID (PK), Forename, surname, gender, date of birth, address, illness, prioirty)

seen_by (ID(PK) PatientID(FK to Patient.PatientID), NurseID(FK to Nurse.NurseID) )

Nurse (NurseID(PK), Forename, surname)
```

Any suggestions to what I'm doing wrong? Thankyou in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select p.*,s.*,n.* 
from patient as p inner join seen_by as s 
on p.PatientID=s.PatientID
inner join Nurse as n 
on n.NurseID=s.NurseID
```

if you want, you can add the where at the end

```
select p.*,s.*,n.* 
from patient as p inner join seen_by as s 
on p.PatientID=s.PatientID
inner join Nurse as n 
on n.NurseID=s.NurseID
where p.field='dumbtext'  -- you can add here the rest of the conditions
```

Comment: The PatientID is not entering into the database in the Nurse table. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: what do you mean? nurse table doesn't have patiendID

Comment: Is there a way that I can test if the results show the what patient is assigned to what nurse via PatientID, NurseID?

Comment: yes, make the same query but use `where p.patiendID=123` where 123 is the patient id, that will display all the info of that patient

Comment: PatientID and NurseID are auto_increment. I want to display the firstname, surename, PatientID from Patient and firstname, surname, NurseID from Nurse. Is this possible?

Comment: Could you provide me with an example of the query please? I dont want it to be two queries, just one which fetches the PatientID and NurseID which has been assigned to each patient.

Comment: select p.*,s.*,n.* 
from patient as p inner join seen_by as s 
on p.PatientID=s.PatientID
inner join Nurse as n 
on n.NurseID=s.NurseID
where n.Nurseid='123'

Comment: This is the message I am getting: "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0191 sec )" It does not create a relationship between Patient and Nurse.

Comment: it created it, but the nurse ID that you placed it doesn't exist or doesn't have a relation with any patien, if you can go to www.sqlfiddle.com create a small copy of the 3 tables with some data and we'll test the queries together

Comment: A patient is seen by a nurse. I need a Patient to be assigned to a nurse so there is a relationship between patientid and their assigned nurse nurseid